# Why can't ListView be top level view?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

So to create a Fragment which contains a single ListView, I must do

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Why do I have to place the ListView inside a FrameLayout? Why can't the ListView be the top level view?

**UPDATE**

I kind of asked the question wrong: what I meant is: Why is it not best practice to make the ListView itself the top level view? I always see the FrameLayout wrapper in online codes.

Comment: "I always see the FrameLayout wrapper in online codes" -- please feel free to link to some. Or, as Wikipedians would put it: citation, please. Note that `ListFragment` does not need a layout file if you are just having it manage a single `ListView`.

Comment: one quick example from a "respected" repo: https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/blob/sunshine_master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_main.xml

Comment: The frame layout in that XML serves not purpose unless they are programmatically adding other views that overlay the list view (such as a floating action button)

Comment: In that specific case, I have no idea why they bothered with the `FrameLayout`. I do not see where they are using it in [`ForecastFragment`](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/blob/sunshine_master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app/ForecastFragment.java), where that layout is inflated. It *is* "best practice" to not have a wasted container, and that `FrameLayout` would appear to be a wasted container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can, as long as you don't expect to put anything else in the layout.

FrameLayout, same as Linear and Relative, are containers for several views, but if you only have one you don't need them.

Most layout files seen online assume you may want to expand on your ui by adding necessities like an empty state or fab. Your empty state needs to be on the same layout too.

Comment: Hi. You answered right before I published my update (race condition), sorry. Please see my update.

Comment: Updated with short guessplanation.